# What is the difference between : SAVE / CREATE / PERSIST when it comes to name a method?

Tags: c#, .net, crud

Imagine you have a method on the server side, in one of your entities Repository.

This method INSERTS or UPDATES Foo entities in the Db.

And you need to name this method.

From the naming convention point of view, can you explain the differences -if there is- between those names:

- SaveFoo(Foo foo)
- PersistFoo(Foo foo)
- CreateFoo(Foo foo)
- SaveOrUpdate(Foo foo)

Or what is the naming convention for such methods that only INSERTS or UPDATES to Db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work in a team, you should first try to find out if there is a convention there, as it's usually more important to be consistent than to find the absolute best name for something.

Using *Save* or *Persist* would work, as they don't imply anything about the previous state.

Using *Create* would imply that the item doesn't already exists, i.e. an insert.

Using *SaveOrUpdate* could be somewhat confusing, as *Update* implies that the item already exists, but *Save* doesn't imply anything about the state, so they overlap.

Perhaps *InsertOrUpdate* would be an alternative, or *CreateOrUpdate*. Either would work as *Insert* and *Create* implies that the item doesn't exist yet, and *Update* implies that it does exist, so they don't overlap. They are also more precise than *Save* or *Persist*, as the names specifically say that they handle both insert and update.

Comment: Unless you plan to write separate Insert and Update functions and you need to differentiate, I would never call one InsertOrUpdate.  And if I did, it would only be for a function I used internally by the Save function I wrote on top of that to abstract it away.

Answer (score 3):

What's the purpose of the function?  To save (or persist, if you like) it, right?  You probably don't care whether the function had to insert or update it... that's abstracted away so you don't have to think about it.  So just call it Save or Persist, whichever you prefer.  That's my two cents.

Comment: +1 It's irrelevant to the consumer of the method how the method is implemented, the name should suggest the result of the method. I'd opt for "Save".

Answer (score 0):

Looking at .NET Framework, ConcurrentDictionary<,> uses .AddOrUpdate()